# Software to automate website screenshot capture

Tags: website, automation, screenshot, screen-capture

Do you know any software that can automate the process of getting [screenshots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenshot) of every page of a website? It would act like a spider/[crawler](http://www.leniel.net/2009/08/java-web-crawler-searcher-robot.html)/robot. You name it...

For example: I developed a website and now I'd like to get a screenshot of every page of the site. I of course could do it manually (a lot of work). For each module of the site (Student, Payment, etc) I have different pages (Create, Edit, Details, Delete, etc) forms.

The thing I'm looking for is a software that can visit every link of the site and then capture the screen - a software that can automate the whole process.

It would also be good if the software allowed the user to pass a list of URLs to capture screenshots allowing even more fine grained configuration.

**EDIT:**

I tried Selenium mentioned by Aaron in his [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/300432/software-to-automate-website-screenshot-capture/300471#300471) but I managed to find an app that does exactly what I needed. It's called Paparazzi!. I wrote a blog post to showcase my attempt at Selenium and the findings regarding Paparazzi!'s batch capture functionality:

[Software to automate website screenshot capture](http://www.leniel.net/2011/07/software-automate-site-screenshot.html)

Answer (score 6):

[DRKSpider](http://www.drk.com.ar/spider.php) can be used to crawl a site and provide a listing of links which can then be exported; once you have those links you can leverage [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/download/).

Once you have the list of links you could easily put together an application leveraging  Selenium's API to walk through the URL list capturing screenshots. The Selenium API has built in screenshot functionality making this effort trivial.

Answer (score 1):

As edited in by OP:

> **EDIT:** I tried Selenium mentioned by Aaron in his [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/300432/software-to-automate-website-screenshot-capture/300471#300471) but I managed to find an app that does exactly what I needed. It's called Paparazzi!. I wrote a blog post to showcase my attempt at Selenium and the findings regarding Paparazzi!'s batch capture functionality:
>
> [Software to automate website screenshot capture](http://www.leniel.net/2011/07/software-automate-site-screenshot.html)